# AnyLogic: Unblock a hold-element after a specific time

Tags: java, anylogic

I am looking for a way to unblock a hold-element after a certain amount of time. i.e hold-element is blocked on t1 and I want to unlock it after t1 + 30seconds.
Is there a smart way to do that? I cannot use a fixed schedule or something since the intervals between blocking/unblocking is always different

Answer (score 1):

you can have an event associated to your hold.

You can use an even triggered by timeout and mode "user control"

on the event you will have the code hold.block()

and everytime you want to start the time to block the hold you do event.restart(yourTime)

if you want to cancel the time your can do event.reset()

That's the best way i think